# how to unzip all .gz files in a folder and combine them into a new file without generating uncompressed files for each .gz file

Tags: bash, shell, gzip

I wanted to unzip all .gz files in a folder and combine them into a new file. Can I do it without generating uncompressed files for each .gz file?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this :

```
zcat *.gz > newfile
```

if you want to remove *.gz after :

```
zcat *.gz > newfile && rm -f *.gz
```

Comment: Using && between the commands would avoid deleting the gzips if you run out of disk space or something in the process

Comment: @that other guy: Not quite understand. Can you please give me an example?

Comment: `zcat *.gz > newfile && rm -f *.gz`